# Count subcategories with a condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 2 tables: `categories` and `products`.

Categories have parent-child relationship structure and the data is fetched by joining the same table.

When fetching the data, I have to count:

1. how many ***products*** each category contains which have `stock >= 1`
2. how many ***subcategories*** a category contains which contain at least 1 product with `stock >= 1`

```
SELECT c. * , count( DISTINCT s.cat_id ) AS number_of_subcategories, count( DISTINCT p.id ) AS number_of_products FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN categories s 
  ON s.parent_id = c.cat_id
LEFT JOIN products p 
  ON p.cat_id = c.cat_id AND p.stock >= 1
GROUP BY c.cat_name
ORDER BY number_of_products ASC
```

At the first glance all goes well, but unfortunately I get ***total number of all subcategories***.

Do I miss one more join or what is my problem so far?

Here is the code: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82494/7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter your query to use a subquery to get the number of subcategories similar to this:

```
SELECT c.cat_id,
  c.parent_id,
  c.cat_name,
  count(sp.cat_id)  AS number_of_subcategories,
  count(DISTINCT p.id) AS number_of_products
FROM `categories` c
LEFT JOIN
(
  select distinct s.cat_id, s.parent_id
  from categories s 
  inner join products p
    on s.cat_id = p.cat_id
  where p.stock > 1
) sp
  ON sp.parent_id = c.cat_id
LEFT JOIN products p 
  ON p.cat_id = c.cat_id 
  AND p.stock >= 1
GROUP BY c.cat_id, c.parent_id, c.cat_name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82494/36)

Comment: Wow, that actually is a pretty awesome solution :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `AND` for `WHERE`. Does it work?

Francisco